# When to call TokenValidatedContext.Success()?

Tags: oauth-2.0, identityserver4, .net-6.0, openid-connect, okta-api

I'm using Okta as an external IdP called from Identity Server 4.

I'm using the `OpenIdConnectEvents` and am calling the `TokenValidatedContext.Success()` method in this event:

```
    private Task OnTokenValidatedImpl(TokenValidatedContext context)
    {
        context.Success();            
        return Task.FromResult(true);
    }
```

In the callback method, I noticed even with `context.Success()` commented out, `result.Succeeded` is still true:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Callback()
    {
        var result = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync("Identity.External");            
        if (result.Succeeded) {} // This is true
    }
```

What is the point of `TokenValidatedContext.Success()` and when should it be called?

Comment: Why do you call AuthenticateAsync? That is typically done by the CookieHandler middleware.

Comment: @ToreNestenius So I can access `result.Principal.Claims` in order to get the user's email address.